# login with curl php

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to login to a website using curl, however I cant get it to work.
This is the code that I am using.

First I get the csrf token from the website to make sure that it matches.
But the result what I get back is always the login form.

```
$url="http://www.example.com/accounts/login"; 
$postinfo = 'csrfmiddlewaretoken='.$key.'&login=email@gmail.com&password=mypassword';

$cookie = "cookies.txt";

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec($ch); 

return $result;
```

Does anyone know why I can not login?

The form fields are correct and also when I do a login attempt the cookies.txt file has changed.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I dont see any error's but just to let you know I am using laravel 5

Comment: You may want to add the tag for it, there might be some relevance to it. I couldn't say for sure if it has a bearing on it, since I don't know anything about Laravel.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I added the error_reporting at the the construct function of the base controller, every other controller extends this controller. But I didnt get any error's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reasons are:

1. You're re-initializing curl after you get the CRSF token, so it becomes invalid for the subsequent request, because that's a completely different session as far as the site is concerned.
2. Your `$postinfo` is a string, so you need to `urlencode()` the values by hand (`CURLOPT_POSTFIELD`S also accept associative arrays, in which case you don't need to do that).

Comment: I already tried with urlencode and also with an array but this did not change anything. However I am doing 2 curl requests, could that be a problem? If so how am I able to get the csrf token?

Comment: You either need to `urlencode()` the token, the username and the password, or use an array. The way it is now (with `@` that's clearly not percent-encoded) won't fly. The number of request doesn't matter, as long as you don't call `curl_init()` in between. And be sure to set `COOKIEFILE` and `COOKIEJAR` before the first GET so that curl gets session cookies and re-sends them with the subsequent POST.

Comment: Yes it was indeed the csrf token.

Answer (score 1):

There are several suggestions I can think of. These are based on earlier experience when it didn't work for me and I finally got it to work through trial and error.

Make sure cookies.txt is writable. Place cookies.txt in a separate folder somewhere outside your www-root and change the value of $cookie with the absolute path:

```
$cookie = "/path/to/writable/folder/cookies.txt";
```

After attempting to login, check if the file contains cookie values. If it does contain cookie values, but not the ones that you need to be recognized as logged in, there may be some additional server side checks to prevent forms to be submitted from outside the server besides the token check.

See what the URL is of the normal human login form, e.g. http://www.example.com/accounts/loginform.html - or the URL you use to obtain the token and add that as referer:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.example.com/accounts/loginform.html');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
```

Set some options that make you appear even more human:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip,deflate,sdch");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
        'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'Origin: http://www.example.com',
        'Cache-Control:no-cache',
        'Connection:keep-alive',
        'Pragma:no-cache',
        'Expect:'
    ));
```

The above example header array worked in my particular case. In your case there may be other headers sent along when a human logs in. Try logging in once using a browser and in the browser's developer tools check the request headers that are sent along and copy/paste them instead. Also doublecheck what is posted for hidden values (in my case needed to add "&__VIEWSTATE=somereallylongIIScode" to the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS string).

Comment: Thanks for your help, the correct url was a little bit different then I thought cause it wasn't ````http://www.example.com/accounts/loginform```` but ````'http://www.example.com/accounts/loginform/```` Would have never tought that it would be a part of the issue.

Comment: Great, happy you got it to work.. I needed the above to get mine to work :-)